# GridView: Capturing and Usng Binary DataKey

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which is populated from a database based on the values specified in some DropDown lists. I am able to insert new rows into the database using the GridView but am having issues in updating an already existing row.

I understand that to update a row into the database, I set a DataKeyName on the GridView, capture the DataKey value for the selected row and pass that as a parameter into the SQL procedure.

1. Setting DataKey

This is my basic GridView Set up (I removed the formatting related code).

```
<asp:GridView id="Application_GridView" runat="server"
         DataKeyNames="appln_OID"
         ShowFooter="True"
         OnRowEditing="Application_GridView_RowEditing"
         OnRowUpdating="Application_GridView_RowUpdating"
         OnRowCancelingEdit="Application_GridView_OnRowCancelingEdit"
         AutoGenerateColumns="false"
```

2. Capturing DataKey value for selected row

This the point where I am stuck -  my DataKeyName appln_OID holds binary value. 
I have seen examples where the DataKey is an INT or string 
eg:

```
int intforumid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0]);
```

or

```
string val = (string)this.grid.DataKeys[rowIndex]["myKey"];
```

but can't find how to capture the binary value.

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx, it should be a Byte[] so I tried this

```
GridViewRow row = ((GridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex];
string applnkey = Application_GridView.DataKeyNames[row.RowIndex];
Byte appln_oid = Convert.ToByte(Application_GridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
```

which gives the error *Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.*

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong in trying to get the binary DataKeyName value!

Comment: Why using binary datatype as a unique key into your database? why use integer and set that as identity(1, 1)?

Comment: That's just how the entire DB system was designed - with all ID columns set to binary values.

Comment: could you try (byte)Application_GridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex];

Comment: byte appln_oid = (byte)Application_GridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]; doesn't compile. 

I used (byte)Application_GridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value; I get the exception "Specified cast is not valid"

Comment: If your column is a byte array (as opposed to just byte), then try:
 
byte[] appln_oid =  (byte [])Application_GridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message :

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'

seems to suggest that the underlying column is actually a byte array, not a byte. If this is the case, you can try :

```
 byte[] appln_oid = (byte [])Application_GridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
```

If that still doesn't work, you can try :

```
string info = Application_GridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.GetType().ToString();
```

run this through the debugger, and let us know what is in "info" after that line of code is run. This will let us know the data type of the field.

Comment: So the byte[] worked  :) Thank you so much!

I ran the 
Type info = Application_GridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.GetType();
and it returns 
info {Name = "Byte[]" FullName = "System.Byte[]"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType} 
This looks like a useful troubleshooting tool ! (Also, seems I need to brush up byte v/s byte array)